# Auto Increment URL ID numbers within a Range

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I need to be able to do a sort of Find and Replace within an HTML document where the search would be for all numbers within a certain range. But I need each number to be replace with an increment of itself. For example, I have a list of links within a page that all look like this:

```
.../click.asp?aid=702134570
.../click.asp?aid=702134571
.../click.asp?aid=702134572
```

Every day those links need to be updated with new links that are auto generated for us. The only part of the URL that changes are the numbers at the end, and they would all increase by the same amount. So if the next lot of links generated looked like this:

```
.../click.asp?aid=762184547
.../click.asp?aid=762184548
.../click.asp?aid=762184549
```

So every link 'aid' would increase by exactly 60049977. The problem is this number would change every day and obviously so would the range it would search within. I know Dreamweaver find and replace option supports regular expressions and I feel that this might be possible this way, but after an extension search I haven't found anything and I'm not familiar enough with regular expressions to know what to try. Thank you in advance.

Comment: it seems to me that your best bet, if it's within the spec and capabilities of your server, would be to generate these links dynamically rather than having them hardcoded in an html document.

Answer (score 0):

The find and replace functionality within Dreamweaver should be able to find the links you want to change by searching for click.asp?aid=

You could even try to include the trailing numbers by checking the "Use regular expression" box and searching for:
click.asp\?aid=\d+

However, there isn't anything built in that will allow you to automatically replace the values by adding a specific number.

Theoretically, you could create a command within Dreamweaver that would allow you to do a direct replacement on the source with the appropriate adjustment using the JavaScript String.replace() method that will allow you to specify a function as the second parameter, than a simple string. But to do that, you'd have to learn how to create a [Dreamweaver extension](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/extend/index.html).

And as Mala suggests, this should be something that is dynamically generated, not relying on a human to make this change every day.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning numbers directly, use some variables..
You can use scriptlets..
I think this may help..